# how to get the data within the period?

Tags: php, laravel

We have an Article Table, has articles.
The article has publish_date and expire_date, which are nullable.

```
Article Table
 $table->date('publish_period_from')->nullable();
 $table->date('publish_period_to')->nullbale();
```

We want to retrieve articles, which are on published at that time.
This is our query.

```
$query->where('publish_period_from', '<=' today())
      ->where('publish_period_to', '>=' today())
```

but in this case, if an article's date is "null", we can't retrieve the article data.

Do you know how to retrieve it?

converting the columns from nullable() to required is better??

we are using
 laravel5.5

Comment: Only you can answer the _converting the columns from nullable() to required is better??_ question. Is there any situation in your system where a row would need to be created without a from and to date?

Comment: Or you could just [read the documentation](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/eloquent-for-orwhere-isnull) and also select the rows with NULL dates or https://hdtuto.com/article/laravel-where-null-and-where-not-null-eloquent-query-example- or maybe https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/wherenull-vs-wherecolumn-null?page=0

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work fine:

```
$query->where(function ($query) {
    $query->where('publish_period_from', '<=' today())
          ->where('publish_period_to', '>=' today())
})->orWhere(function ($query) {
    $query->whereNull('publish_period_from')
          ->whereNull('publish_period_to');
})->get();
```

That will return the results where it is published within that time constraint, or where both values are null.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method `->orWhereNull('field')`